# Black Screen on Boot-up Ubuntu 20.04 LTS when not plugged in, Dual Graphics Vega 8 and GTX 1650

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a strange situation. My Ubuntu installation works fine when I plug in the laptop and boot into it. Everything works as it should. But, if I boot in without plugging the laptop, the whole screen turns black. I can't use my keyboard, so can't alt ctrl del. I think it's an issue with the Vega integrated graphics not being compatible or something. When I plug in, the Nvidia card kicks in and does stuff pretty good. Of course, this switching is based on my observations on Windows. I don't know if it's the same deal with Linux.

**My Specs: Asus TUF FX 505 DT**

Ryzen 5 3550H

Radeon Vega 8 Integrated Graphics + Nvidia GTX 1650

8GB RAM

Windows on SSD and Ubuntu on HDD's 100 GB Partition (three partitions 30 / + 16 swap + 54 home) .

Both UEFI, fast-boot disabled. I did a minimal install with no third-party drivers.

> before someone marks this as duplicate, please do note that I have issues only when NOT plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue, here's how I solved it:

1. Boot into Ubuntu with power plugged in. Hopefully, you should be able to successfully boot.
2. Modify the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` kernel variable in `/etc/default/grub`: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"`
3. `$ sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot.
5. Install proprietary drivers from Nvidia.

Hopefully, that solves the issue.